# Explicit construction of Kähler differentials in a general category.

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category. Then we can form the tangent category $T_C$ whose objects are pairs $(X, M)$ where $X$ is an object of $C$ and $M$ is an abelian group object of $C/X$. We have a functor $p: T_C\to C$ such that $p(X, M) = M$. According to the nLab page on [Kähler differentials](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K%C3%A4hler+differential), $p$ has a left adjoint $\Omega: C\to T_C$ such that $\Omega(X) = (X, \Omega_X)$ where $\Omega_X$ is some kind of generalized "module of Kähler differentials." However, I can't find an explicit construction of this left adjoint. Apparently the construction of this left adjoint appears in the $\infty$-categorical setting in Lurie's paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3091.pdf), but unfortunately I can't understand that so I'm hoping to work out this construction in the setting of ordinary categories.

Just to be clear, I understand that this gives the ordinary module of Kähler differentials when $C$ is the category of rings. I'm just wondering how to explicitly construct this left adjoint in a general category.

**Edit**: The left adjoint evidently does not exist for every category. However, I'm still interested in what kind of categories have Kähler differentials (other than the canonical example of a locally presentable category), and how they could be explicitly constructed.

Comment: I am sure the left adjoint does not exist for a general category. You probably need to assume that the category is nice and then use an adjoint functor theorem.

Comment: So I have the following idea trying to relate Lurie's paper to the nLab on the [adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem#InLocallyPresentableCategories): Let $C$ be a locally presentable category. Then $T_C$ is also locally presentable and the functor $p: T_C\to C$ is accessible and preserves small limits. Therefore, $p$ has a left adjoint. Is this the full argument? So that it suffices to assume that $C$ is locally presentable?

Comment: Well what I am saying seems to be Proposition 4.1 on the page for [Beck module](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Beck+module).

Comment: Nevertheless, there are categories like the (opposite) category of schemes which have Kähler differentials but is not a locally presentable category. So this locally presentable criterion is not all-inclusive.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether the sheaf of Kähler differentials on a non-affine scheme can be obtained by this construction. You should probably check that first.

Comment: The nlab page does *not* state that this left adjoint exists for any category $C$, right?

Comment: That's right it doesn't explicitly say that the left adjoint always exists. I just misinterpreted in a few places where it speaks of "the left adjoint" when perhaps it should say "when the left adjoint exists."